# req.next is not a function [CLOSE]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm making a website. I am in the dashboard stage and have a problem because I get the error `TypeError: req.next is not a function`. I want to make a dashboard subpage. I am using the isAuthorized function to check if the user is logged in.
Please help.

```
C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: req.next is not a function
    at done (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1007:25)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:642:5)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\src\routes\dashboard.js:31:21
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\src\database\database.js:35:9)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\olios\Desktop\Moje rzeczy\Avi\Boty\Auth\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

dashboard.js

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const database = require('./../database/database')
const fs = require('fs')

const dirAdmin = __dirname + `./../public/config/admin.yaml`

let data

data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(dirAdmin))

function isAuthorized(req, res, next){
    if(req.user){
        next()
    }else{
        res.redirect('/auth')
    }
}

router.get('/', isAuthorized, (req, res) => {

    database.sql("SELECT * FROM servers", (rows) => {
        for(const f of data){
            if(f == req.user.id){
                res.render('dashboard/dashboard', {
                    guilds: req.user.guilds,
                    servers: rows,
                    user: req.user,
                    admin: true
                })
            }else{
                res.render('dashboard/dashboard', {
                    guilds: req.user.guilds,
                    servers: rows,
                    user: req.user,
                    admin: false
                }) 
            }
        }
        
    })
})

router.get('/admin', isAuthorized, (req, res) => {
    database.sql("SELECT * FROM servers", (rows) => {
        for(const f of data){
            if(f == req.user.id){
                res.render('admin/admin', {
                    guilds: req.user.guilds,
                    servers: rows,
                    user: req.user,
                    admin: true
                })
            }else{
                res.render('admin/admin', {
                    guilds: req.user.guilds,
                    servers: rows,
                    user: req.user,
                    admin: false
                }) 
            }
        }
        
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

auth.js

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const passport = require('passport')

router.get('/', passport.authenticate('discord'))
router.get('/redirect', passport.authenticate('discord', {
    failureRedirect: '/',
    successRedirect: '/dashboard'
}), (req, res) => {
    res.send(200)
})

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    if(req.user){
        req.logOut()
        res.redirect('/')
    }else{
        res.redirect('/')
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

discordStretegy.js

```
const DiscordStrategy = require('passport-discord').Strategy
const passport = require('passport')
const { User } = require('./../database/database')

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log("Serialize")
    done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    console.log("Deserializing")
    const user = await User.findOne({
        where: {
            id: id
        }
    })

    if(user){
        done(null, user)
    }
})

passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.CLIENT_REDIRECT,
    scope: ['identify', 'email', 'guilds'],
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

    try{

        const user = await User.findOne({
            where: {
                id: profile.id
            }
        })

        if(user){
            console.log("User exists.")
            done(null, user)
        }else{
            console.log("Create new user.")
            const newUser = await User.create({
                id: profile.id,
                username: profile.username,
                avatar: profile.avatar,
                discriminator: profile.discriminator,
                locale: profile.locale,
                email: profile.email,
                guilds: profile.guilds
            })
            done(null, newUser)
        }

    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        done(null)
    }
}))
```

Comment: Please share the content of the file where you create your authentication strategy

Comment: you will have to do `return res.redirect('/auth')` and also because in else if you don't return anything the middleware needs `next()` to go to the next handler

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar still not working

Comment: There is no `req.next` in your code. have you saved your changes?

Comment: Do you use it inside the client's html somehow?

Comment: @TasosBu Not. I'm using Discord authorization and I'm on the Discord authorization page

Comment: In which file/lineNumber is this error triggered?

Comment: @TasosBu to go to the page /dashboard/admin I have to authorize and that's when I throw an error and the application crashes

Comment: even if I remove the isAuthorized functions, I keep getting the same error

Comment: From the error you posted, it is triggered in this line: `src\routes\dashboard.js:31:21`. Which is probably when it tries to do `res.render`, what is rendered in `dashboard/dashboard` ? can you attach the code for it?

Comment: @TasosBu This is that line of code `res.render('dashboard/dashboard', {`

Comment: Its file dashboard.ejs in folder dashboard

Comment: Can you include this file in your question?

Comment: this file is already there, it's called dashboard.js

Comment: 2nd code in my problem

Answer (score -1):

You can simply change your code like:

```
if(!req.user){
 res.redirect('/auth')
}
```

Comment: It is not a good solution. Without the next() function, the page does not change after authorization